# how to Clone a row containing text box and dynamic dropdown box in a table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a table containing a row in which a text box and a dynamic drop-down list is present and i want to clone that row. To do that i am doing the below :

## Below code is for displaying the tabel containng a row which has a text box and dynamic dropdown box:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="j" class="i">
        Skills
        <input data-bind="value:skl" name="skl" id="skl" style="width: 120px; height: auto"
            data-type="string" class="k-textbox" />
        <input id="styp" style="width: 120px; height: auto" /><span></span>
        <button class="add" value="add">
            Add</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        @* <span data-for="styp" class="k-invalid-msg"></span></td>*@
    </td>
</tr>
@*this code is to display the add rows and delete rows functionality*@
<tr id="fo" style="display: none">
    <td width="100%">
        <input type="text" class="k-textbox" id="a" width="100 px" height="20 px" />
        <select style="width: 90px; height: auto" id="options" data-bind="value:skill" data-text-field="skill"
            data-value-field="skillid" data-source="skilldatasource" data-role="dropdownlist">
        </select>
        <button type="button" id="b" class="delete" value="delete">
            Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


//Below code is for defining datasource to the dropdownlist

var skilldatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read:
        {
            url: "/ProfileMgmtProfileSearch/Skills",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
        }
},
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "skillid",
        fields: {
            skillid: { type: "number" },
            skill: { type: "string" }
        }
    }
}
})

skilldatasource.read();

$(document).ready(function () {
//Add button click functionality to Add new row to the Skills row with same fields //and also append a delete button to it:
$('.add').click(function () {
    alert("cliked");
    id++;
    var prot = $("#fo").find("td").clone();
    // $("#options").clone();
    prot.attr("class", "")
    prot.attr("id", id);
    prot.addClass("new");
    $('<tr/>').append(prot).insertAfter($('#theTable tbody>tr:last'));
    var dropdownlist2 = prot.find("select#options");
    alert("hai....");
    alert(dropdownlist2);
    dropdownlist2.kendoDropDownList({});
});

// button click functionality to delete the specified row containing that delete button
$('#theTable').delegate('.delete', 'click', function () {
    $(this).closest("td").remove();
    var first = dropdownlist.dataSource.get(c--);
    dropdownlist.dataSource.remove(first);
})
});
```

=============================================================================

```
Here by executing the above code am able to clone the entire row but the dropdown box is not getting values in it i.e., datasource is not cloned, so plz help me out of these problem.
```

Comment: Can you try with jQuery clone() function?

Comment: Thanks For your suggestion, can you provide an example..

Comment: hi Ruqsana  let say you want to clone a table which you show in code just try  var clonetable=$(table).clone(); asumed u have jquery knowledge